# Dropdown option menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a website with javascript dropdown option menu.

This is my menu.php file

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="/home.php">Home</option>
<option value="/aboutme.php">About Me</option>
<option value="/work.php">Work</option>
<option value="/contect.php">Contect Me</option>
</select>
```

I have included this file on every pages of website.
It works fine.

Now what I want is : When I click on the **aboutMe** from dropdown menu in "home" It should redirect me to **About Me page** and dropdown menu in **aboutme** page should remain at **about me**. So far it is redirecting successfully, but dropdown menu always remains on "Home".

Is there a way to solve this ? or Should I create a saparate file for each pages?

I am confused. Please Help.

Comment: set selected property to option elements as per page. it will work fine.

Comment: You may need to pass the value via the querystring and use that on the target page to set the drop down accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your select an id:

```
<select id="page" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
```

and use the script:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('page').value =  window.location.href;
  }
</script>
```